# Show json data in a dropdown in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-forms

This is the json url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

This is the json structure:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
```

I wish to show all the `title` in a dropdown.

Comment: Please, share what have you tried so far and point out where is the problem.

Comment: @user2828442 check out my answer  and the live demo on Plunker below and if you still have any question just let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <select>
      <option  *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.title">{{item.title}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
})

export class App {
  items : any;
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .subscribe(res => this.items = res.json());
  }
}
```

Working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4WKM0FzWz6N279NKAEf?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

check out the working Plunker I created with a slick material design styling and with some simple error handling

{{ [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8FL0N4Cc59xHpSjpnhZ?p=preview) }}

[image]

in your component you do the following:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx'

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles: [`
  div {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .subscribe(res => this.items = res.json(),
    err => console.error('Error: ' + err),
    () => console.log('Voila! you got your list!'));
  }
}
```

and then in your template you add this:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
<h4>Show json data in a dropdown in angular2 - Hamed</h4>
</md-toolbar>

<div> 
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">data dropdown menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item?.title">{{item?.title}}</button>
</md-menu>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let todos = "the json data " // make a http call to subscribe to the data

    <select [ngModel]="selectedtitle" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="select">
        <option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i.title of todos">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
```